# Bash script - could someone proof read and explain why it is wrong

Tags: bash, ubuntu, if-statement

Тhis is the first script I've ever written and I'm looking for some help. I can't find a script like the one I'm trying to write and its becoming a bother because I wish to create more/expand upon such a bash structure.

If some one has the time could they maybe proof read this for me. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong and why?

```
#! /bin/bash
#  script to turn the screen blue
echo -e '\033[1;32m'
echo "Minecraft Server LTG Bukkit 1.4.7"
echo "Minecraft Server LTG Bukkit 1.4.7"
echo -e '\033[31m' "[Start  ] \033[1;32m LTG MineCraft Server"
echo -e '\033[31m' "[Stop   ] \033[1;32m LTG MineCraft Server"
echo -e '\033[31m' "[Restart] \033[1;32m LTG MineCraft Server"
echo -e '\033[0m'
cho -e "Hello, \033[47m \033[30m"$USER" \033[0m Enter Command:"

echo  "Command:"
read  $COM1 start stop restart

if ["$COM1" = "start"]:  then
       echo "ran minecraft serv"
     if [ "$(pgrep -g java -Xmx256M -Xms256M -jar /minecraft/minecraft_server.jar)" ] ; then
       echo MineCraft Server Bukkit 1.4.7 L.T.G : Running

     else
       echo -e "\033[1;32m MineCraft Server Bukkit 1.4.7 L.T.G : \033[31m  FAILED \033[0m"
     fi
if ["$COM1" "stop"]: then
    echo -e "\033[1;32m  MineCraft Server Bukkit 1.4.7 L.T.G : Shutting Down \033[0m"
    killall java
     if (( "$(pgrep -g java -Xmx256M -Xms256M -jar /minecraft/minecraft_server.jar)" )) ; then
    killall java
    echo -e "\033[1;32m MineCraft Server Bukkit 1.4.7 L.T.G: is SHUTDOWN \033[0m"
     fi
if [ "$COM1"  "Restart" ] ; then
     echo MineCraft Server Bukkit 1.4.7 L.T.G : Rebooting
     exit 1
 fi
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Not without hearing the symptoms.

Comment: why dont you present the errors that are facing while execting it.BTW the first two if conditions are wrong.correct them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take two lines...there's enough there to keep us busy.

```
read  $COM1 start stop restart

if ["$COM1" = "start"]:  then
```

The first line reads into a variable whose name is stored in `$COM1` (which is uninitialized, so in fact it is empty, so it doesn't do anything after all), plus the three variables `start`, `stop`, and `restart`.  You either need:

```
read COM1 start stop restart
```

or you need to initialize `COM1` before you use it.

The second line manages to run into a surprising number of issues.

1. The `test` command, aka `[`, is a command name, not a symbol.  As such, it needs to be separated from its arguments.  Note that there usually is a command `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[`, though it is also a shell built-in these days.
2. Fortunately, since `$COM1` is unset and empty, it already is separated, but more by accident than design.
3. Because of that, your `[` command is executed with 3 arguments: `=`, `]:` and `then`.  This is not a valid invocation of `[`.  The last argument should be `]` on its own.
4. You should use a semi-colon to separate the `]` from the `then`.

In aggregate, you should have written:

```
if [ "$COM1" = "start" ]
then
```

or you can add a semi-colon (which does not have to be separated from the `]` by a space) and then the `then`:

```
if [ "$COM1" = "start" ]; then
```

---

Stylistically, you have the string '`Minecraft Server LTG Bukkit 1.4.7`' repeated all over the place; don't!  Use a variable to hold it.

Worry about your embedded cursor control sequences; different terminals have different sequences, so you're restricted to a single terminal type.  Fixing that is harder; investigate the `tput` command.

Answer (score 0):

alright so this is what i ended up with- it works but i want to know if there are ways of improving such a disaster
i really do appreciate the response :)

```
#! /bin/bash
#  script to turn the screen blue
NAME=$(echo Minecraft Server LTG Bukkit 1.4.7)
echo -e '\033[1;32m'
echo "$NAME"
echo "$NAME"
N1=$(echo LTG MineCraft Server)
echo -e '\033[31m' "[Start  ] \033[1;32m $N1"
echo -e '\033[31m' "[Stop   ] \033[1;32m $N1"
echo -e '\033[31m' "[Restart] \033[1;32m $N1"
echo -e '\033[0m'
echo -e "Hello \033[47m \033[30m"$USER" \033[0m Enter Command:"

echo  "Command:"
read test
#this is a test piece
echo "start = $test"

if [ $test == "start" ];  then
echo -e "\033[31m $NAME : Starting"
java -Xmx256M -Xms256M -jar /minecraft/minecraft_server.jar &>./minecraft.sh.rlog
  if [ "$(pgrep -g java -Xmx256M -Xms256M -jar /minecraft/minecraft_server.jar)" ] ; then
       echo -e "\033[31m $NAME : Running"
       exit 1
  else
    echo -e "\033[1;32m $NAME : \033[31m  FAILED \033[0m"
  fi
fi
if [ $test == "stop" ]; then
    echo -e "\033[1;32m $NAME : Shutting Down \033[0m"
        killall java &> ./minecraft.sh.log
        MINECRAFT=$(pgrep -g java -Xmx256M -Xms256M -jar /minecraft/minecraft_server.jar                             &>./minecraft.sh.log)
                sleep 1
                echo .
                sleep 1
                echo .
                sleep 1
                echo .
                sleep 1
                echo .
     if [[ -z "$MINECRAFT" ]] ; then
        killall java &> ./minecraft.sh.log
        echo -e "\033[1;32m $NAME : IS SHUTDOWN \033[0m"
     else
         #should never bee seen
        echo Something Went Wrong
     fi
fi
if [ $test == "restart" ] ; then
     echo -e "\033[31m $NAME : Rebooting \033[0m"
        kill java &>minecraft.sh.log
        sleep 1
 echo .
        sleep 1
        echo .
        if [[ -z "$MINECAFT" ]]; then
        echo -e "\033[1;32m $NAME : IS SHUTDOWN \033[0m"
        sleep 1
        echo .
        fi
        echo -e "\033[31m $NAME : Starting \033[0m"
        sleep 1
        echo .
         java -Xmx256M -Xms256M -jar /minecraft/minecraft_server.jar &> ./minecraft.sh.rlog
else
if [ $test == "exit" ] ; then
        exit 0
fi

exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why not: `NAME="Minecraft Server LTG Bukkit 1.4.7"` and `N1="LTG MineCraft Server"`.  The result is the same; the code is simpler.